# How to get value of particular column value after running openshift command using shell script?

Tags: shell, kubernetes, openshift

I am running below command in openshift platform which produces some output

oc get pods

name  status

job1  Running

job2  Completed

How to extract only status from the above result and store it in a variable using shell script.

ex : status=completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to extract only status from the above result and store it in a
> variable using shell script.
>
> ex : status=completed

Try `status=$(oc get pods -o=custom-columns=STATUS:.status.phase --no-headers)`. You can `echo $status` and see the list of status saved in the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you add --output=json to your commands you can use JQ to select the status. I find bash scripts great for using commands but there are a lot of drawbacks when it comes to parsing output. With JSON you can regardless of the format select the correct key.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
 JQ is not installed in my openshift platform . Is there any other way to extract result

Comment: @Prabhakar you don't install jq on openshift, jq is a command line tool installable on your local machine and you can combine it with oc command, there is also another tool named yq that supports both yaml and json.